# Cant Use Method getHelper('questio*n') on Symfony 2.5

Tags: symfony, console, helper

I'm trying to put some confirmation advise on my Symfony 2.5 application, I'm following a simple implementation from the Symfony Docs of the `getHelper('question')` method but my application can`t find the method and I cant understand why. Following my code.

My Controller:

```
...

use Symfony\Component\Console\Question\ConfirmationQuestion;

...

class UserController extends Controller
{

  ...

  public function subscribeCourseAction($userId, $courseId){

        ....

        $helper = $this->getHelper('question');
        $question = new ConfirmationQuestion('Confermare la sottoscrizione?', false);
        if (!$helper->ask($input, $output, $question)) {
            return OK
        }
        else return "some stuff";
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
EMERGENCY - Call to undefined method My\MyBundle\Controller\UserController::getHelper() 

CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedMethodException: "Attempted to call method "getHelper" on class "My\MyBundle\Controller\UserController" in .../Controller/UserController.php line 276." at .../Controller/UserController.php line 276
```

I'm probably doing something very stupid but cant realy see it, please help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what docs are you following here exactly? A `Controller` doesn't have a `getHelper()` method, hence the error.

You are trying to use a `Console\Question\ConfirmationQuestion` in a controller class, and that's the reason of your error. You're mixing concepts here.

Comment: i'm following this docs http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/questionhelper.html

Comment: Well, that's it! You're writing a controller, not a console command. You've mixed up these concepts, as methods that belong to a console command are not present in a controller.